# How to add a specific package from an already added Library using Swift Package Manager?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I'm using Xcode 14.2 and SwiftUI for making an iOS App. I have already added firebase-ios-sdk library to the project with some of the packages in it. But I now need to add another package that I previously hadn't.

Swift Package Manager won't let me access the Firebase library again since it's already been added.

In the current scenario Cocoa Pods is not an option. Is it possible through the SPM route?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add additional package products, in your target's "General" tab, find the **Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content** and click the **+** button

[image]

then select the additional libraries:

[image]

Comment: see also https://www.kiloloco.com/articles/010-add-package-product-xcode/